# Replace a tag placement from a group to another - Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

Can I replace a tag  placement from a group to another ?

https://jsfiddle.net/0hmpa26j/

From Select2's Document:

> https://select2.org/tagging#customizing-tag-placement-in-the-dropdown

```
insertTag: function (data, tag) {
    // Insert the tag at the end of the results
    data.push(tag);
}
```

It pushes the tag into another `data` object. And when I remove it from the `input` it also gets deleted from the `data` object.